# how to use params data in other component in angular

Tags: angular, angular8

In my app component. I'm having components like

app.component.html

```
<app-toolbar></app-toolbar>
<app-loader></app-loader>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

and in my app.component.ts

I'm subscribing data from the query params like

```
this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
  const { statusBoolean } = params;
  this.myService.status = statusBoolean;
});
```

here what I'm trying is I'm having a button in my toolbar. whenever the statusBoolean is true in params then I have to display the button in the toolbar.

in myService.ts:

```
status: boolean;
```

in my toolbar component:

```
<button mat-button *ngIf="myService.status"></button>
```

and I tried by set and get params in service and access the params in toolbar component I'm not getting any values and also by parent-child communication nothing worked . here my toolbar component is loading first and unable to get data from service and throwing undefined. can anyone please help me with this.

Comment: where is your myService file?

Comment: in my services folder which is injectable in root

Comment: I mean can you post your myService and toolbar component code?

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar, I think you can define a service bridge between your toolbar and other components:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ToolbarService {
  private toolbarComponent: ToolbarComponent = null;

  public registerComponent(component: ToolbarComponent): void {
    this.toolbarComponent = component;
  }

  public setStatus(value: boolean): void {
      if (this.toolbarComponent) {
         this.toolbarComponent.setStatus(value);
      }
  }

}
```

In tool bar component:

```
public status: boolean = false;
public ngOnInit(): void {
   this.toolbarService.registerComponent(this)
}

public setStatus(value: boolean): void {
    this.status = value;
    this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges(); // I think should work without it
}
```

And you can use `toolbarService.setStatus()` everywhere

You can also try a simpler solution, declare the status as observable:
myService.service.ts

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class MyServiceService {
  public status: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

  public setStatus(value: boolean): void {
     this.status.next(value);
  }
}
```

And just subscribe to value in toolbar component:

```
public ngOnInit(): void {
  this.myService.status.subscribe(status => {
    this.status = status;
  });
}
```

Do not forget to unsubscribe from subscription in ngOnDestroy